# R as.numeric in a formula

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
x<-c(0,2,1,0)
A<-c(1,3,4,3)
df<-data.frame(id,x,A)
```

now I want to make a variable called `value` in a way that if x>0, `value` for each `id` would be equal to A+1/x, and if x=0, value would be equal to A.
with this aim I have typed

```
value <- df$A + as.numeric(df$x > 0)*(1/df$x)
```

what I expect is a vector a follows:

```
[1] 1 3.5 5.0 3
```

however what I get by typing the above command is :

```
 [1] NaN 3.5 5.0 NaN
```

I wonder if anyone can help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be simpler to use function `ifelse` in this case:

```
ifelse(df$x>0, df$A + (1/df$x), df$A)
[1] 1.0 3.5 5.0 3.0
```

See `?ifelse` for more details.

With the command you were trying to apply, although `as.numeric(df$x>0)` was indeed giving you a vector of 1 and 0 (so it was a good idea), it didn't change the fact that `1/df$x` was an `NaN` when `df$x` was equal to 0 (since you can not divide by 0).